# Swift Tableview Cells populated with name and a Int value

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsmutablearray

I'm trying to build my first app and i'm hitting a wall

I have a view controller and inside this view controller is a UITableView

Now I have been able to populate this view controller using an array.count

I have been able to add an accesory checkmark when i tap on the item to mark sa completed

Now my problem is that i want to tap on an item, mark it as completed AND when completed to have a value written on a label

each cell would have a different Int value

I've read somewhere that to do so i would need to use NSMutableArray but i don't know how to use this

any help would be really appreciated

heres the code :

UPDATED may 8 1215 utc

```
import UIKit

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {                        //class and subclass                  |)
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/
    // Variable and constant, also IBAOutlet


    struct CellData
    {
        var title: String
        var value: String
        var selected: Bool

    }

    var CellData1 = CellData(title: "this is a test", value: "1", selected: true)
    var CellData2 = CellData(title: "this is a test", value: "1", selected: true)
    var CellData3 = CellData(title: "this is a test", value: "1", selected: true)
    var CellData4 = CellData(title: "this is a test", value: "1", selected: true)

    var tableArray: [CellData] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var scoreshow: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // checkmarks when tapped

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
            if cell.accessoryType == .Checkmark
            {
                cell.accessoryType = .None
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            }
            else
            {
                cell.accessoryType = .Checkmark
                cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()            }
        }    
    }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //number of sections for the table

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Calculate the amount of rows

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.tableArray.count;
    }
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //Cells text label and config

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{


        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
        cell.textLabel!.text = (tableArray[indexPath.row]).title
        scoreshow.text = (tableArray[indexPath.row]).value
        cell.textLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None;

        return cell
 }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //resetbutton

    @IBAction func resetcheck(sender: UIButton) {

            for i in 0...tableView.numberOfSections()-1
            {
                for j in 0...tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(i)-1
                {
                    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: j, inSection: i)) {
                        cell.accessoryType = .None
                        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    }

                }
            }
        }

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Your updated code doesn't make sense. You have 2 different definitions of CellData: One as a class and the other as a struct. Your class definition creates what looks to me like an infinite recursion crash in the making (each CellData object creates 9 other CellData objects, which will in turn create 9 more each (81) which will create 9 more each (729 in the 3rd pass, etc).  The struct version has the same problem.

Comment: ok so i should delete the var tableArray = [CellData]

Answer (score 0):

So first what you should probably do is create a new subclass of NSObject and set it up so it takes properties such as objectText and objectValue.

You then create as many objects as you want and store these in an NSMutableArray

NSMutableArrays are the same as what you have done here..

```
let section1 =
    ["this is used",
     "this is used to test",
     "this is used to test the lenght",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",
     "this is used to test the lenght of the text",]
```

Sort of... except you will want to make it a var rather than let so that you can modify it.

You'd end up with something like:

```
let object1: MyNewModel = MyNewModel("this is used", value: 1)
section1.append(object1)
```

That's if you create a decent init method for your model that you can easily set it up.

You can now use this mutable array to populate your tableview in the same way as you are doing, but instead of just setting the text to that object in the array you would set it to:

```
((MyNewModel)section1[indexPath.row]).objectText
```

The next thing you'll want to do is subclass UITableViewCell and inside the cell position some labels that you wish to populate with the text inside these models. So give them some public properties to access the labels inside the table cell, replace this line:

```
let cell:UITableViewCell =
UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
```

With this:

```
let cell = MyNewTableCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")
```

You will then have access to your new labels inside the cell and set them as so:

```
cell.myTextLabel!.text = ((MyNewModel)section1[indexPath.row]).objectText
cell.myValueLabel!.text = ((MyNewModel)section1[indexPath.row]).objectValue
```

And you can hide or show whichever you want to show whenever..

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'm new in swift so just creating an int for this is hard for me, i'll work on that and let you know if i have any developpment

Comment: I'm stuck at the beginning completely, I cannot figure out an init() method that works with the code <br let object1: MyNewModel = MyNewModel("this is used", value: 1)
section1.append(object1)  /br>

Comment: When you create a new class, a subclass of NSObject you make an init method like normal, something like this: 

`class TestObject: NSObject {
   
    init(objectTitle: String, objectValue: Int) {
        super.init()
        
        
    }
    
}`

Comment: Formatting is a bit crappy on comments sorry

Comment: Inside that init method you then set the values onto a var that is a property of the class, then you should be able to access those properties from your tableview

Comment: so something like this : `class CellData: NSObject {
    
    
    init(objectTitle: String, objectValue: Int) {
        
        var object1: CellData = CellData(objectTitle: "this is used", objectValue: 1)
        section1.append(object1)
        
        
        super.init() }
    
}`

Comment: I'll add my CellData.swift to my question

Comment: unresolved identifier section1, but i know it'S unresolved i just dont know how to

Comment: should I put the identifier before init() then after add data with section1.append

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your approach.

When the user does something to a cell (like select it) you are grabbing the cell (using `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath()`) and changing it.

That is the wrong way to do things.

What you want to do is have an array (mutable array, or a `var` array in Swift) that records the current state of your able view. Text contents, integer values, selected state, etc.

Then in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, configure the cell using the data in the array.

If the user taps a cell, fetch the array entry for that cell, change it, and then tell the table view to redraw that cell (using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths).

I would suggest creating a struct to store all the info for your cell:

```
struct CellData
{
  var title: String
  var value: Int
  var selected: Bool
}
```

...

```
var tableArray: [CellData]
```

Then write your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method to configure the cell by fetching those values from your array of structs.

Your code creates 3 different immutable arrays section1, section2, and section3, but then numberOfSectionsInTableView returns a fixed value of 5, and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` always returns cells built from section1. That's screwy.

If you're just playing, skip sectioned table views for now. It will confuse you. Start with a single-sectioned table view, get the hang of that, and then deal with sectioned tableviews later.

When you are ready for sectioned table views, try using an array of arrays:

```
//The array for a section is an array of CellData
typealias sectionArray: [CellData] 

//The array for the whole table is an array of sectionArray arrays.
var tableArray: [sectionArray]

init()
{
  tableArray = [ 
    sectionArray[
      CellData(title:"section 0, row 0", value: 0, selected: false],
      CellData(title:"section 0, row 1", value: 1, selected: false],
      CellData(title:"section 0, row 2", value: 2, selected: false]
    ],
    sectionArray[
      CellData(title:"section 1, row 0", value: 10, selected: false],
      CellData(title:"section 2, row 1", value: 11, selected: false],
      CellData(title:"section 3, row 2", value: 12, selected: false]
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your detailled info I'll try right now, As for multiple arrays, i've done those for 2 reasons 1st is test the length and the amount of rows and 2nd is because eventually when the app is functional i want to separated my data in 5 sections (with headers in footers) now should i go ahead with the sectioned view or should i start with 1 array and work from there

Comment: again thanks for your answer but i don'T see how this fit's in my project

Comment: It fits your project because it is how you should work with table views. Manipulating the cells directly is **WRONG**, and will cause you a wide variety of problems.

Comment: ok, well i've tried incorporating it inside the project and it means that my reset button, cells populating method, and touch to complete method will become obsolete, i'll be honest i'm all about going the right way, but I've spent a lot of time getting just those 3 things to work and my knowledge in swift is too small for me to start again from scratch, i'll keep on trying it's just really hard to put all of that together

Comment: That is a mistake that will come back and bite you. Your current approach is absolutely, without a doubt wrong. Imagine this: You have 30 entries in your table view. The user selects different cells and enters different data in the first few cells. Then the user scrolls down by 10 or 15 cells. The top-most cells scroll off the screen, and their data is **lost forever**. When the user scrolls back to the top of the table view, the cells will show their old values, and the changes will be lost.

Comment: This is not a Swift thing, it's an iOS design thing. You can't store state data in table view cells because they can be scrolled off-screen and discarded at any time without warning.

Comment: OK, well that is a problem I am encouring right now, as soon as I scroll down my completed checkmark disappears, so you're telling me that using your method should solve this issue plus give me the values I need for my text label?

Comment: Yes. That is the cause of your problem.

Comment: OK, i've modified my view controller code, now i have no data but now error at least, see it in your answer

Comment: So post your new code as an update at the bottom of your question: The code that creates your data structure, and your new `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Comment: I've updated the whole code, i did not change much in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, i know its wrong i just don't know how to do it, also the CellData var is wrong i'm pretty sure....